# How to compare any string from output through shell script of unix command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I get a log file as soon as I run one command(process is still running in background). Now I want to fetch the status (clean or un-clean) from that log file. If status is clean then I will leave the process as is else, if it is un-clean then I have to kill the process which was started by my first command and re-run the same command again.

I have tried with `cat logfilename | grep "un-clean"`. But I don't know how to verify this output in shell script.

I want something like (roughly) `var= clean then the output of above command == var if yes then echo "ok" else re-run command`

I have tried some of the commands but not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you want this structure

```
if grep -q "un-clean"  /path/to/log_file.log ;
then
    # put some command in case we find result is unclean
else 
    # if the output is ok, do something else
fi
```

All it does is to silently (without printing to screen) check if there is  a match of string "unclean" in the file . If there is we do the if part, otherwise - we do else part.

Here's an example:

```
$> if grep -q 'root' /etc/passwd ; then  echo "This user exists" ; else echo "This user doesn't exist"; fi    
This user exists
$> if grep -q 'NOEXIST' /etc/passwd ; then  echo "This user exists" ; else echo "This user doesn't exist"; fi 
This user doesn't exist
```

What also can be done is to start command you want from script, but in background. That way we can have it's PID. Here's what I mean

```
$> echo "HelloWorld"   &                                                                                      
[1] 6876
```

Adding `&` causes `echo "HelloWorld"` run in background, and we have it's PID stored in `$!` variable.  Thus, we can do something like,

```
some-command  &
CMD_PID=$!
if grep -q "un-clean"  /path/to/log_file.log ;
then
         kill -TERM $CMD_PID
else 
        # if the output is ok, do something else
fi
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) its working....finally....was waiting since long

Comment: @SiddharthTiwari glad I could help. If this post has solved your question, please mark it as accepted ( there's a gray check-mark next to up-down arrows )

Comment: i dint get that kill process part.. i would be appreciated if you help me in detail... i am sorry i am very new to this.. just working from past two days

Comment: @SiddharthTiwari  basically  , if you run command with `&` ,  you can save it's process ID . And if you have process ID, you can kill that process. `-TERM` just sends `SIGTERM` signal to that command.  That signal just allows for nicer closing of command instead of just abruptly stopping it

Comment: For example, if I have script and run `firefox &` then `FOXPID=$!` I can start firefox, remember its PID, and then continue running other commands. Then later I can use that PID to kill firefox

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that:

```
some-command  &
PID=$!
wait $PID
while grep -q un-clean filename.log ; do
  kill -TERM $PID
  some-command  &
  PID=$!
  wait $PID
done
```

the process will be killed (see `killall`: `man killall`) and `re-run` command will be run while the file `filename.log` contains the string `un-clean`.

Does it help?

EDIT: post updated using the good @Serg solution and added the `wait` command to wait for the end of the command before checking the log file.

Comment: yes it is but its getting into infinite loop. any suggestions for that?

i have 4 more process running in background so will **kill process** kill those as well?
how to use kill process command?? directly shall i write **kill process**

Comment: Maybe you will have to insert a `sleep 5` after the re-run command to wait 5 seconds after launching the command to wait the execution before searching for the result? But if you only want to retry one time, the @Serg solution is better.

Comment: no i want to have a loop cz it may show un-clean for 4 - 5 times in a row so loop is better but its getting into infinite loop

Comment: updated my post to avoid infinite loop (if the command only show un-clean for 4 - 5 times)